# python numpy optimization n-dimensional projection

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, projection

I am relatively new to python and am interested in any ideas to optimize and speed up this function. I have to call it tens~hundreds of thousands of times for a numerical computation I am doing and it takes a major fraction of the code's overall computational time. 
I have written this in c, but I am interested to see any tricks to make it run faster in python specifically.

This code calculates a stereographic projection of a bigD-length vector to a littleD-length vector, per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection. The variable a is a numpy array of length ~ 96.

```
import numpy as np 
def nsphere(a):
    bigD = len(a)
    littleD = 3
    temp = a
# normalize before calculating projection
    temp = temp/np.sqrt(np.dot(temp,temp))
# calculate projection
    for i in xrange(bigD-littleD + 2,2,-1 ):
        temp = temp[0:-1]/(1.0 - temp[-1])
    return temp
#USAGE:
q = np.random.rand(96)
b = nsphere(q)
print b
```

Comment: I'm confused -- in your for loop, you aren't using the index `i` anywhere. So you just progressively divide `temp` by `1.0-temp[-1]` a lot of times?

Comment: @tpg2114 - in each iteration of the loop, `temp` is shrunk by one because `[0:-1`] doesn't include the last item. So the operation is not as simple as you are suggesting. But I agree it is strange to explicitly control the start and stop values of `i` when it is never referenced.

Comment: hi - yes, i is not used, this is a admittedly silly way to repeat this process 96-3 times, but indeed that is all it is. I am wondering if reassigning temp[] to a 1-element shorter vector each time is slow, would it be faster to pre-allocate a 96-3 length list of vectors of length 96, 95, 94 ... to 3 ? I don't know how this works in detail in python.

Answer (score 2):

This should be faster:

```
def nsphere(a, littleD=3):
    a = a / np.sqrt(np.dot(a, a))
    z = a[littleD:].sum()
    return a[:littleD] / (1. - z)
```

Please do the math to double check that this is in fact the same as your iterative algorithm.

Obviously the main speedup here is going to come from the fact that this is a O(n) algorithm that replaces your O(n**2) algorithm for computing the projection. But specifically to speeding things up in python, you want to "vectorize your inner loop". Meaning try and avoid loops and anything else that is going to have high python overhead in the most performance critical parts of your code and instead try and use python and numpy builtins which are highly optimized. Hope that helps.

Comment: @ Bi Rico - Thanks and this indeed runs faster but it does not compute the same thing, and the results are different. This is necessarily a N^2 problem. Should I provide more details on how this works ?

Comment: @user1850461 If you go though the math I'm confident that you'll find this is the same as the function you provided in your question. I also tested this function against the function in your question and it gives the same result. Of course if you provided a simplified version of the true function you're trying to optimize, this may not be that useful.

Comment: ok, problem solved. my function (not shown here, in the actual code I am using - my fault for the confusion) normalized the result before returning and yours did not, I added a line to return the result normalized and they agree perfectly on real data now. Thank you very much for this solution, it runs 40~100 times faster depending on the dimensions of the input data, which is massively helpful!